# Automate the process of saying "yes" when uninstalling a program

Tags: uninstallation

So Im currently working on a program that will uninstall bloatware on a computer automatic and afterwards install several drivers. I have managed to open the uninstaller for the programs, but here lays the problem. Several uninstallers have "yes/no" buttons to press before actually uninstalling, McAfee for example. Is there a way to make a script saying yes to these uninstallers?

Comment: Please also state your operating system and add appropriate tags.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: Im using win10, the problem is mostly mcafee.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs will have an "-unattend" or "-silent" switch you can use on the executable allowing not displaying prompts but this is obviously application specific.

There isn't really a good reliable way to do what you want - you could use an Autohotkey script to try to click on the button (or hit tab and enter till the button is accepted) but won't work very well for non-standard installers or if they change the layout between versions etc. so will be a lot of work to maintain, but may be feasible if your just targeting one or two problem programs...